# SAS SQL Date formatting

Tags: sas

Just wondering how I can alter the following query to show date in the format I want. I am using SAS to pull this data.

Existing Date format: 15MAR2011:09:05:16.000000

Format I want: 15MAR2011:09:05:16

Query I am using:

```
proc sql;
create table data.test as
select       * from connection to odbc
(
select     ID,
             DATE AS CREATION_DATE,

from         maintable
);
quit;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `format` affects how SAS displays a variable value.  It does not affect the actual value itself.

So, assuming the variable CREATION_DATE is a datetime value, just assign it a format of DATETIME20. to display is as you want:

```
proc sql; 
   create table data.test as
   select ID, CREATION_DATE format=datetime20.
   from connection to odbc 
   ( select ID, DATE AS CREATION_DATE
     from maintable );
quit;
```

However, some ODBC interfaces will return your date column as a character string, so you need to be sure it is showing up on the SAS side as a proper datetime value.

Comment: I tried adding this to my version of the code (I noticed you modified the SQL statement) but it did not work. Do I need to use it in the form you have posted?

Comment: The only change I made was to your outer SELECT statement, which defines the columns using SAS syntax. Your inner SELECT is executed by the remote data source using ODBC. If you have other columns in your inner SELECT, you need to add them to the outer SELECT. And if you have an error, please give the message. Saying only "it did not work" isn't useful.

Comment: thanks for the input! I understand now - the outer select is "setting up" the structure of the table and the inner select is populating the data from ODBC. Question: why are we not using the select * from statement in the inner select? Will it still select*?

Comment: In this case, it is because you need to use SAS syntax to define the variable's `FORMAT` attribute.  Using plain old "select *" just copies the values back into SAS variables.  There are several other SAS variable attributes you can specify, such as `LABEL` and `INFORMAT`.